# TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerVoipToken' of null

Tags: android, react-native, voip

I have a legacy react-native project. I'm using `react-native-voip-push-notification`

The issue arises whenever I attempt to invoke `VoipPushNotification?.registerVoipToken()` in my code, resulting in the error;

"Cannot read property 'registerVoipToken' of null" in `node_modules/react-native-voip-push-notification/index.js` at line 95 `RNVoipPushNotificationManager.registerVoipToken()`

`node_modules/react-native-voip-push-notification/index.js`

```js
    static registerVoipToken() {
        RNVoipPushNotificationManager.registerVoipToken();
    }
```

Causing the app to crash. I've tried to find a solution but haven't found one yet. Crash occurs only in android